# Setting OnFocusChangelistener for RatingBar?

Tags: android

I have the following code and for some reason , the onFocusChange doesn't get executed? It works for an Edittext thought.

Code:

```
if (rBar.getOnFocusChangeListener() == null)
   rBar.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                           // do something
                        }
                    });
```

I have tried the other SO questions related to this like setting: but no success

```
rBar.setFocusable(true);
rBar.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to do some stuff like setting related params based on the rating when focus gets changed